# Reducing OpenMP overhead

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize some IIR filtering code, so far using `gcc` 7.2 and `gomp`.

Here's the relevant section of code:

```cpp
void par_iir(std::vector<std::vector<double>>& data, const std::vector<double>& B, int order) {
    int N = data[0].size();
    const int CHUNK_SIZE = 32768;
    int chunks = ceil((double)(N - 2) / (double)CHUNK_SIZE);
    int gChunk;

    #pragma omp parallel private(gChunk) shared(chunks, order, B, data)
    {
        for (gChunk = 0; gChunk < chunks + order - 1; gChunk++) {
            #pragma omp for
            for (int i = 0; i < order; i++) {
                auto chunk = gChunk - i;

                if (chunk >= 0 && chunk < chunks) {
                    auto sz = chunk == (chunks - 1) ? (N - 2) % CHUNK_SIZE : CHUNK_SIZE;
                    auto inp = data[i].data();
                    auto out = data[i + 1].data();

                    filter(inp + chunk * CHUNK_SIZE + 2, B.data() + i * 5, out + chunk * CHUNK_SIZE + 2, sz);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function filter is defined as follows:

```cpp
inline void filter(const double* in, const double* B, double* out, int sz) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        out[i] = in[i] * B[0] + in[i - 1] * B[1] + in[i - 2] * B[2] - out[i - 1] * B[3] - out[i- 2] * B[4];
}
```

`par_iir` defines a cascaded IIR filter and `filter` applies a single bi-quad in the cascade. `order` determines how many cascaded bi-quads make up the filter. My computer has 4 cores (8 threads) and I've chosen a filter with order 8.

Since IIR filters have loop dependencies, I've opted to divide the work into chunks (currently of a fixed size of 32768.) The idea is that once a chunk for bi-quad `i` in the cascade is completed, then bi-quad `i` and `i+1` can run in parallel to completion.

I was expecting that this should result in close to all 8 threads being maximally used, so an improvement of close to 8x. Instead, I typically see about 33% load on each thread.

Using `perf` I've profiled the code and found that ~63% of the time is spent in `gomp_thread_start`. This ~63% doesn't change even if I increase `N` and `CHUNK_SIZE` proportionally.

Where is this 63% overhead coming from? And secondarily, is there a better way to write this code?

---

Some details on IIR filters in case it helps:

For my purposes, an IIR filter is made of up multiple bi-quad filters. Each bi-quad filter performs the following operation, where the `a` and `b` values are constants:

`out[n] = b0*in[n] + b1*in[n-1] + b2*in[n-2] - a1*out[n-1] - a2*out[n-2]`

Each section of the cascade is given the output of the prior section as its input. This makes most approaches to parallelism unworkable.

Comment: Do you call `par_iir` many times? If you call it once, threads should be started only once. In this case, it might not be worth parallelizing your code (starting threads takes more time than computation). If you call it multiple times, you might want to parallelism at a higher level.

Comment: Yes, I call `par_iir` multiple times. In total my application might spend about 1 minute in `par_iir` in the single-threaded case. If I increase `N` and `CHUNK_SIZE` such that each call to par_iir takes about 1-2 seconds, I still see the same 63% overhead.

Comment: If one call takes 1s, creating threads should be negligible. This is odd behavior. Do you have the opportunity to test with a different compiler, of on a different OS?

Comment: A different OS will be harder. I'll see if I can make `clang` work with openmp.

Comment: Are you on MacOS? Homebrew installs a Clang with OpenMP. On Linux it shouldn't be a problem, Clang does OpenMP natively everywhere except MacOS. :)

Comment: I'm on Fedora 27. Using `-fopenmp` seems to result in undefined references to functions from Intel `MKL`...

Comment: Sorry to hear that... library compatibility is an issue with OpenMP.

Comment: How many threads does it create? You're expecting 8, but maybe you have an OMP environment variable set that causes more threads to be made? You could e.g. set the number of threads to 2 in your `omp parallel` pragma, see if you still see the same behavior.

Comment: With `num_threads(2)`, only 2 threads are spawned. `gomp_thread_start` is only 45.5% now. Interestingly within that `gomp_barrier_wait_end` and `gomp_team_barrier_wait_end` combine for 26% of that 45%.

Comment: Humm... `order==8`? OpenMP might be assigning the first 4 loop iterations to one thread, and the last 4 to the other. In that case, for the first 4 chunks, the second thread is only waiting, and until chunk 8 it doesn't have as much work as thread 1. You might have to tell the compiler explicitly how you want your for loop to be spread across threads. How large is `chunks`? It should be much larger than 8 to give your 8 threads enough work. Are you sure that that is not what's happening?

Comment: Also check this: http://forum.openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=306 -- it looks like `gomp_thread_start` might be doing more than starting threads.

Comment: Yes, I'm starting to think the same thing. I rebuilt this using `std::async` and `std::future` and I'm getting basically the same result.

Comment: If you use MKL, you must consult the Intel MKL link advisor applet, as it is impossible to guess the library invocation for gcc.  If you have further questions, they may be more appropriate to Intel MKL forum.

Comment: I'm not using MKL. I looked up the undefined symbol errors `clang` gave me and found that they come from MKL. Chances are it is actually `libiomp` that it wants, which isn't packaged in Fedora.